# Why is my process of finding the ratio in which C divides A & B not working?

Tags: coordinate-systems

Suppose, I have three points: $A(2,5),B(7,9)$ & $C(5,\frac{37}{5})$. Now, I need to find the ratio in which $C$ divides $A$ & $B$. Now, let us use the internal section formula:

$$(x,y)=(\frac{m_1x_2+m_2x_1}{m_1+m_2}, \frac{m_1y_2+m_2y_1}{m_1+m_2})$$

where $(x,y)$ divides the line segment created by $(x_1,y_1)$ & $(x_2, y_2)$ internally in the ratio $m_1:m_2$. Now, let $C$ divides $A$ and $B$ in the ratio $m_1:m_2$. Now,

$$\frac{7m_1+2m_2}{m_1+m_2}=5$$

$$\implies7m_1+2m_2=5m_1+5m_2$$

$$\implies2m_1-3m_2=0...(i)$$

Again,
$$\implies\frac{9m_1+5m_2}{m_1+m_2}=\frac{37}{5}$$

$$\implies45m_1+25m_2=37m_1+37m_2$$

$$\implies8m_1-12m_2=0$$

$$\implies2m_1-3m_2=0...(ii)$$

Here, the equations $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are the same. So, how am I supposed to find $m_1:m_2$? Is my process wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly both equations will be the same as the ratio that $C$ cuts $AB$ should be the same regardless of how the segment is projected.

Once you got $2m_1-3m_2=0$ you should have continued like
$$2m_1=3m_2$$
$$\frac{m_1}{m_2}=\frac{3}{2}$$
$$m_1:m_2=\boxed{3:2}$$

The fact that there are infinite solutions to $2m_1-3m_2=0$ is because equivalent fractions/ratios can be made by multiplying the "numerator" and "denominator" both by a constant. Regardless, the value of the ratio between the two variable is always invariant despite the fact that there are infinite solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a quicker way to calculate the ratio which is different than my way?

Comment: Once you have verified that $C$ lies on $AB$, the ratio which $C$ divides $AB$ is $\frac{5-2}{7-5}=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I didn't quite understand how you got to the form $\frac{5-2}{7-5}$. Could you please give me the general form? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a theorem that explains this, but it is pretty intuitive (and not hard to prove) that ratios of distances on a line segment are preserved under a orthogonal projection onto another line. The horizontal distance between $A$ and $C$ is $5-2$. The horizontal distance between $B$ and $C$ is $7-5$. Hence, the ratio that $C$ cuts the line segment is just the distance to $A$ divided by its distance to $B$, which is $\frac{5-2}{7-5}=\frac{3}{2}$. You could also use the vertical distance (or any other projection), but that was a little more computationally difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The ratio is obviously $3:2$.

However, a more intuitive way of understanding it would be to let the ratio be $k:1$ rather than $m:n$.